# Get number of combinations of x different balls in a bag with a capacity of y

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know if the title is okay, but let me explain:

We have 2 different types of balls (A, B) and I want to know the number of combinations **without repetition** that I can get in a bag that can contain 4 of them.
This is a basic example and we can calculate it fast with our mind, these are the combinations:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | A |
| A | A | A | B |
| A | A | B | B |
| A | B | B | B |
| B | B | B | B |

It gets way more complicated if we add more different types of balls.

I'm totally lost on how to discover the formula with non repetitions (I'm not a mathematician so sorry if this is very simple, I just can't find anything similar and I've been trying really hard with the knowledge I have). How can I get the number of non repeated combinations?

Comment: This type of problem can be solved using the technique often called "stars-and-bars."  You want to know, for fixed $k, n$, how many solutions are there in non-negative integers to $x_1+x_2+ \ldots +x_n=k$.  That answers the question for $k$ balls of $n$ different types.  Separate $k$ indistinguishable "stars" by $n-1$ indistinguishable "bars" and you can read off a solution to this equation, so the answer is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.  I'd make this an answer but I'm sure a search of the site for stars-and-bars will get you plenty of duplicates to your question.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you, this is what I was searching for, now I'm struggling to implement it into an algorithm but that's another story.
Thanks a lot!